# Scala, type clases and enforcement

Tags: scala, typeclass

It was in a case where it was necessary to have something very similar to Guava MultiSet. I've already used the scala MultiMap, mixing it as a trait and. I try to do something for the MultiSet.

```
trait MultiSet[A] extends mutable.Map[A, Int] {

  def setCount(e:A, count:Int):Unit = {
    this.update(e, this.getCount(e) + count)
  }

  def getCount(e:A): Int = this.getOrElse(e, 0)

}
```

And i use it as:

```
scala> val degree = new mutable.HashMap[String, Int] with MultiSet[String, Int]

scala> degree.getCount("a")
res0: Int = 0

scala> degree.setCount("a", 1)

scala> degree.setCount("a", 2)

scala> degree.getCount("a")
res1: Int = 3
```

I wanted to do an extra step (probably unnecessary, with Int should be enough) and i write this:

```
trait MultiSet[A, T] extends mutable.Map[A, T] {

  def setCount(e:A, count:T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]):Unit = {
    this.update(e, num.plus(this.getCount(e), count))
  }

  def getCount(e:A)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = this.getOrElse(e, num.zero)

}
```

My question is there's a way to do *enforcement* over T, to tell the compiler that should be exist a Numeric[T] for that type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround with companion object

```
  trait MultiSet[A, T] extends mutable.Map[A, T] {

    protected def numeric: Numeric[T]

    def setCount(e:A, count:T):Unit = {
      this.update(e, numeric.plus(this.getCount(e), count))
    }

    def getCount(e:A): T = this.getOrElse(e, numeric.zero)
  }

  object MultiSet {
    def empty[A, T: Numeric] = new mutable.HashMap[A, T] with MultiSet[A, T] {
      val numeric: Numeric[T] = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
    }
  }

  val degreeInt = MultiSet.empty[String, Int] // Ok
  val degreeString = MultiSet.empty[String, String] // Compile Error
```

Comment: Is a good way to enforce it on "creation". I like it. Thanks!